# What is standard I/O for Disc

Tags: linux, hardware-raid

I have raid5 and 6 HD one HD size is 1TB. In the Nagios monitoring most of the time we saw error for Disc IO usage critical we set 3000 as a warning and 3500 as a critical error in nagios plug-in for this Disc IO usage. Can anyone help our what is the standard IO for RAID5.

> megasasctl

```
| a0      | PERC H730 Mini | encl:1 ldrv:1 | batt:FAULT, low voltage 
|---------|----------------|---------------|-------------------------
| a0d0    | 5586GiB RAID 5 | 1x6           | optimal                 
| a0e32s0 | 1117GiB        | a0d0          | online                  
| a0e32s1 | 1117GiB        | a0d0          | online                  
| a0e32s2 | 1117GiB        | a0d0          | online                  
| a0e32s3 | 1117GiB        | a0d0          | online                  
| a0e32s4 | 1117GiB        | a0d0          | online                 
| a0e32s5 | 1117GiB        | a0d0          | online
```

> iostat -dx

Linux 3.16.0-59-generic (as03)  26/10/16    _x86_64_    (32 CPU)

```
| Device: | rrqm/s | wrqm/s  | r/s           | w/s             | rkB/s | wkB/s  | avgrq-sz | avgqu-sz | await  | r_await | w_await | svctm | %util |
|---------|--------|---------|---------------|-----------------|-------|--------|----------|----------|--------|---------|---------|-------|-------|
| sda     | 0.41   | 1099.86 | 14.29 2658.28 | 869.90 16850.50 | 13.26 | 0.15   | 0.05     | 1.84     | 0.05   | 0.03    | 9.21    |       |       |
| sdc     | 0.00   | 0.00    | 0.00          | 0.00            | 0.00  | 0.00   | 8.00     | 0.00     | 6.68   | 6.68    | 0.00    | 6.68  | 0.00  |
| sdb     | 0.00   | 0.00    | 0.03          | 0.69            | 0.12  | 335.12 | 927.77   | 0.14     | 188.05 | 11.65   | 195.94  | 4.44  | 0.32  |
| dm-0    | 0.00   | 0.07    | 0.03          | 0.68            | 0.12  | 335.12 | 938.43   | 0.33     | 465.86 | 21.56   | 485.75  | 4.50  | 0.32  |
```

Comment: There's no standard, you benchmark **your array** to determine max values of the performance counters you want to monitor and derive reasonable thresholds from there.

Answer (score 4):

While there is no "standard" IOPS values for any array, please pay attention to your battery: according to `megasasctl` output, your batter is failed (`batt:FAULT, low voltage`) and this **will** severely affect RAID5 performance.